# One Class Classification on high dimensional space

Tags: machine-learning, classification, outliers, one-class

I want to solve OCC(one class classification) on images, the input would be an image, the output is if the image belong to the class, and I extract the image feature from a deep neural work, the feature is in a very high dimension, more than 25000, I find that the Nearest Neighborhoods would be less meaningful when the point in a high dimensional space on this [paper](https://members.loria.fr/MOBerger/Enseignement/Master2/Exposes/beyer.pdf), the LOF(Local Outlier Factor) algorithm wouldn't make sense.

Can someone point me in right direction?

Comment: @user77876 Hello, can you give me some suggestions? will the methods in [Intrinsic Dimensional Outlier Detection in High-Dimensional Data](http://www.nii.ac.jp/TechReports/public_html/15-003E.pdf) and [HiCS: High Contrast Subspaces for Density-Based Outlier Ranking](https://www.ipd.kit.edu/~muellere/publications/ICDE2012.pdf) work for me?

Answer (score 1):

Your two best choices are either dimensionality reduction or another algorithms that doesn't rely on distance measures.

If you have plenty of images, you may train a neural network and don't need to do dimensionality reduction or other feature engineering.

If you don't have so many images to train a neural net, try to find a way to extract features from your images first and classify on those features.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, but it seems that I'm facing an OCC problem, I will never have enough images on the negative class, It's easy to find images showing a specific object, but hard for images not showing the object. And I don't have too much knowledge on image processing, I'm afraid I can't get enough features from the image, that's the reason why I extract features from pre-trained convolutional neural networks. I wonder if I can solve the problem based on this [paper](http://www.nii.ac.jp/TechReports/public_html/15-003E.pdf).